# Return the size of file

Tags: c++

I have a function that i use to return the size of file

```
float filesize( const char * filename){
    struct stat buf;
    stat(filename, &buf);
    return buf.st_size;
}
```

I am trying to find out  elegant way ,how  to return size in mb / gb / kb instead of big numbers ? + extenstion e.g

```
 1,25gb
12,44kb
```

I tried returning ostream e.g

```
ostringstream filesize( const char * filename){
    ostringstream os;
    struct stat buf;
    stat(filename, &buf);
    if( buf.st_size > 1024000){
        os << setprecision(2) << (float)buf.st_size/1024000 <<"mb";
    }else if( buf.st_size > 1024){
        os << setprecision(2) << (float)buf.st_size / 1024 <<"kb";
    }
    return os;
}
```

This throws

```
 error: use of deleted function
```

in returing os.

Why did this error occur ? Also , is there any other way to return size in gb/mb/kb ?

Comment: I suggest you should return `std::string`, not `ostringstream `.

Comment: Binary mega is not 1024000.

Comment: If you take a closer look at the error message, it should explain which deleted function you are attempting to use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you take a look at [this list of constructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream/basic_ostringstream) that `std::ostringstream` has, you'll find that it has no copy constructor. Therefore it is not copyable.

When you return an object by value, such as your `ostringstream filesize` function does, a temporary return value is copy-initialized from the expression passed to the return statement. So, what you're trying to do, is return a **copy** of `std::ostringstream` object. But, as we have established, that type is not copyable. That is why your compiler is explaining to you, that you tried to use the **deleted** copy constructor.

Note, that since C++11, `std::ostringstream` does have a move constructor, so if your compiler supported the current standard, then the program would be legal.

Solution: Compile with C++11 or later standard enabled, or don't return a `std::ostringstream`. Perhaps returning a `std::string` would be more appropriate.